# WebGL CORS: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.

Tags: javascript, html, cors

How do I get Cross-Origin Resource Sharing to work properly with WebGL textures? I think I took all the steps I needed to.

- The image is located at `http://localhost:15555/imgbuttons/nexthand.png`.
- The JavaScript code is:

  ```
  var res = new Image();
  res.crossorigin = "anonymous";

  res.onload = function () {
      if (ondone) {
          var tex = new cc.Texture2D();
          tex.initWithElement(res);
          tex.handleLoadedTexture();
          ondone(tex);
      }
      res = null;
  };

  res.src = "http://localhost:15555/imgbuttons/nexthand.png";
  ```

  Where `.handleLoadedTexture()` fails on the following line:

  ```
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this._htmlElementObj);
  ```

  Where `this._htmlElementObj` is the aforementioned `Image`.
- And the server sends the image with the following response headers:

  ```
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
  ```

Shouldn't this be [all the required ingredients](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/using-cors-to-load-webgl-textures-from-cross-domain-images/)? What am I missing?

I do note that `Origin: null` is **not** in the request headers. Maybe this is the issue, but I'm not sure why it isn't - shouldn't `res.crossorigin = "anonymous";` have taken care of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! The reason is that the attribute is case-sensitive and is actually called `crossOrigin`:

```
res.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```